# Jquery ajax display database data without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, popup

I'm really new to jquery and ajax and am struggling with how to go about doing this. 
I'm using jquery mobile 1.4.1 and I'm trying to show form data that has been saved to the database without refreshing the page from a popup.

I have a page where I click on a button to open a popup. The user can enter information into the popup and when submit is clicked the form data is passed to my php script via ajax to update the database; this works.

This is the popup form:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#submit').click(function()
        {
            $.post("submitNewCustId.php", $("#addId").serialize(),  function(response) 
            {
                $('#success').html(response);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div data-role='popup' id='addCustId' data-theme='a' data-overlay-theme='a' data-dismissible='false' style='min-width:300px;'>
<div data-role='header' data-theme='a'>
    <h1>Add Identification Type</h1>
</div>
<div data-role='main' class='ui-content'>
    <form id='addId' action ='newcustomerid.php' method='post' >
        <input type="hidden" name="cust_id" value='<?php echo $custid; ?>'>
        <input type="hidden" name="sess_id" value='<?php echo $sid; ?>' />
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="phoneType">Type</label>
                    <select name="idType" id="idType" data-native-menu="false">
                        <?php echo $idInnerOptions; ?>
                    </select>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="phoneNumber">Description</label>
                <input type="text" name="idDesc" id="idDesc" value="">
            </div> 
            <div class='ui-grid-a'>
                <div class='ui-block-a'><input type='submit' id="submit" value='Update' class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline' data-transition='pop' /></div>
                <div class='ui-block-b'><a href='#' class='ui-btn' data-rel='back' data-transition='pop'>Cancel</a></div>
                <div id="success" style="color:black;"></div>
            </div>
     </form>

</div>
```

This is the PHP (I know its very basic I'll work on the validation etc later):

```
$idType = $_POST['idType'];
$idDesc = $_POST['idDesc'];
$custId = $_POST['cust_id'];
$sessId = $_POST['sess_id'];

$sql = "call theFunction ('". $idType ."','". $custId ."','". $idDesc ."','". $sessId ."')";
$insert = sasql_query($connect, "$sql");
```

However, after my database is updated I want the popup to close and for the initial page to be updated with the new data that has been saved in the database. 
Here is the code that needs to update:

```
    while($row = sasql_fetch_array($idresult))
    {
        echo " 
        <li>
            <div class='container_12'>
                    <div class='grid_15'>
                <div class='ui-grid-a'>
                    <div class='ui-block-a'><div id='idType' class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px; background-color:transparent; border: none; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;'>" . $row['description'] . "</div></div>
            <div class='ui-block-b'><div id='idNo' class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px; background-color:transparent; border: none; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;'>" . $row['number'] . "</div>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='grid_120'>
    <a href='#editCustId' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop' style='padding:0px; margin:0px; border:0px; float: right;' class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-edit ui-btn-icon-notext'>Edit</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </li> 
    ";
        }   //end while
        echo "</ul>";
```

I have no idea how to do this - my problems being 1. how can I close the popup when submit is pressed and 2. how can I update the php while loop to show the new row without a page refresh?
I hope this all makes sense, thanks for your help.

Comment: First, it seems like you have different urls in form action and in ajax post `newcustomerid.php` and  `submitNewCustId.php`. Second, you receive the updated data in response variable, but where is the `success` div?. Third you can close the popup div after the response  is recieved like `$('#addCustId').hide()`

Answer (score 0):

Best method of this is to use `$_SESSION`s and ajax together. Here's my crack at it:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form#addId').sumbit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'yourPHP.php',
            data:{idType:$('select[name="idType"]').val(),idDesc:$('input[name="idDesc"]').val()},
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                //validation here.
                if($('input[type="text"]','form#addId').val().length<3)xhr.abort();//this will prevent the ajax from sending the POST to your php page. IF the values of the text inputs are less than 3.
            },
            success:function(result){
                console.log(result);//shows the result in the console.
                var rowBuilder=result.split(';');
                var rows=new Array();
                rowBuilder.foreach(function(){
                    var temp=this.split(':');
                    rows[temp[0]]=temp[1];
                });
                //hopefully rows is now: rows{'idType'=>'value');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

with your PHP I'd suggest a class structure and to use mySQLi

```
while($row=sasql_fetch_array($idresult){
    echo'rowDescription:'.$row['description'].';rowNumber:'.$row['number'].';';
}
```

also make `cust_id` and `sess_id` `$_SESSION`s like this:

```
$_SESSION['cust_id']=$cust_id;//this will mean you can use the variable on any PHP page within your website once it's been set.
//will require session_start(); on ever line 1 on your page. It HAS to be line 1.
```

the Array rows is now available to put into your previous field before the popup. Hope this helped. Let me know if you have any problems

Comment: thanks I'll have a go with this! Will it all work with sasql (this is a work project and have to use that rather than mysql). Thanks again for your help!